# confirmation of account not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So im trying to create a confirmation of the account, but it's quite not working.

This is login page, and it should check when the account is activated but even if the value is confirmed in database it's always showing that it's not activated, So it's always displaying unactivated messages.

```
if(isset($_POST['login_button']))
{
$userName = $_POST['username']; 
$userPass = $_POST['password']; 

$hashedPass = hash('whirlpool', $userPass);
$query = "SELECT Ime FROM Igraci WHERE Ime = '$userName' AND Lozinka = '$hashedPass'";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $userName, $hashedPass);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

while($conf = mysqli_fetch_assoc(query))
{
    $aktiviran = $conf['Confirmed'];
}

if($row)
{

    if($aktiviran == 1)
    {
        $session = md5($userName.$hashedPass);
        mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE Igraci SET session = '$session' WHERE Ime = '$userName' AND Lozinka = '$hashedPass'");
        setcookie("username", $_POST['username'], time()+3600*24);
        setcookie("authorization","ok");
        header( "Location:welcome.php");
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        echo '
                        <div class="transbox" position = "center">

            <center><p>Ovaj racun nije aktiviran, molimo da ga aktivirate.</p>
            <p>Ukoliko niste primili email proverite junk folder ili ponovo zatrazite aktivaciju racuna.</p>
            </center>

            </div>
        ';

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you get with var_dump($aktiviran); before the if?

Comment: I get null, what does that mean ?
I think the problem is with getting $aktiviran from the database, when i set it like $aktiviran == 0 its ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
if($row) {
     if($row[number of the column 'Confirmed']==1) {
         // do the stuff
     } else {
         // do the other stuff
     }
}
```

This way you won't need the while() and the fetch_assoc() (that is returning null)

Comment: I dont really understand this part

number of the column what should i put there ?

Comment: Actually, you can use the row name as well as the row number: `$row["Confirmed"]==1`.

Comment: Try doing a `var_dump($row)` and verify the `field_count` and `num_rows`.

Comment: i did var_dump returning null

Comment: Just re-looked at the question and it should at least return the 'Ime': `SELECT Ime FROM Igraci WHERE Ime = '$userName' AND Lozinka = '$hashedPass'`. The 'Confirmed' problem occurs because you ain't selecting it, only the 'Ime' row. But you also get no returns from that row. Did you try this query directly in your database (Command Line or PHPMyAdmin)?

Comment: i have re-edited all code from scratch but it's still not working
http://pastebin.com/u7eiX0zP

Comment: And the query results on the MySQL database?

Comment: Try querying the same select as you made in the PHP file. Try also with only the `WHERE Ime='".$userName."'`.

Comment: Not working with the name, i think the problem is with mysqli escape string because name is formated like Joan_Mackey with underscore. But if i remove escape string than it can be easily injected into base

Comment: No, the mysqli_real_escape_string doesn't escape underscores, you can print the $userName that it'll still have the underscore. The problem really is in the SELECT statement, but you need to try each of the rows in the WHERE clause to get the one that is giving you the problem, either on the name or the password.

Comment: Idk, it only works when i delete escape string, but when i put it back on it doesnt.

Comment: It works when you remove the escape string from the userName AND the password or only the name?

Comment: when i only leave AND `Lozinka` = '$hashedPass' with out escaped string it works, but when i escape string on password it doesnt. same thing with username without escaping it works but when i put it under escaped string it doesnt

Comment: Try leaving only the UserName with the escape_string on, and the Lozinka without it.

Comment: Tried that not working, only works without escaping strings

Comment: That's weird. If you print the escaped string, it'll still have the underscore, so it shouldn't affect the SQL clause. You could try using the [addclashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php)